# Is there a way to empty the trash/wastebasket from the command line?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu, directory

This would be great especially considering the latest version of Ubuntu is very slow when displaying directories on my PC...

Comment: Try `rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash`. Found in http://askubuntu.com/a/468722/2273

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At least in Debian and Ubuntu, you can install the `trash-cli` package. This provides a number of commands for working with FreeDesktop.org Trash Specification compliant trash cans, like GNOME's.

```
/usr/bin/trash
/usr/bin/list-trash
/usr/bin/restore-trash
/usr/bin/empty-trash
```

To remove all trashed files, use `emtpy-trash`. It can also just remove files that have been in the trash more than a certain number of days. Use `empty-trash x`, where "x" represents the number of days.

I personally have set up a cron job that runs daily to get rid of trash over a week old.

Comment: that's a great answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing like a system trash in Linux, but its common for many desktop environments to use `~/.Trash` as trash folder. This depends on the window manager you are using.

For Gnome you can empty this folder with:
`rm -rf ~/.Trash/*`

Comment: I suspect the window manager has little to do with what folder is used for trash storage, but I know what you meant :)

Comment: On my gnome system the trash is found in `~/.local/share/Trash`.

Comment: That is only true if all your stuff is on one partition. Every drive/partition has its own trash (wouldn't make sense to move a multiple GB file over to a different drive to store it in the trash)

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of multiple partitions :-) @Steven D: what gnome version are you using? maybe this has changed or is partly distribution specific...

Comment: I wonder if this [trash-spec](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec) would help creating a more generic solution?

Comment: @echox I checked it on GNOME 2.32 distributed by Ubuntu.

Comment: @tante that's the sort of answer I was after, yes

Comment: @echox nice logo. hail to the thief.